# Как удалить кеш файлы оставив файл .htaccess

Tags: php

Очищаю кеш скриптом

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('cache/')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
        unlink("cache/$file"); 
    } 
}
closedir($handle); 
}  

?>
```

Как оставить файл .htaccess в директории cache?

Спасибо!

Comment: `&& $file != '.htaccess'`

Answer (score -1):

можно сделать список файлов, которые не трогать удалялкой

```
$keep_files[] = dirname(__FILE__).'/.htaccess';
```

и делать проверку на соответствие

```
if ($handle = opendir('cache/')) {

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
if(!in_array($file, $keep_files)){
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
        unlink("cache/$file"); 
    } 
}
}
closedir($handle); 
}
```

чтобы не перепутать пути, сначала сделайте print_r(), вместо unlink()

Comment: Казалось бы, ну где Россия, а где [папуасы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Карго-культ)? ан нет, на RU.SO стадами бегают. Увидели, что белый человек `__FILE__` использует, и ну давай из навоза и палок тоже самое лепить к месту и ни к месту.

Comment: а поподробнее? чем путь к файлу не устраивает?

Comment: подумай. головкой своей. она тебе не только для того чтобы в неё есть.

Comment: это не чат доска? либо по делу, либо мимо..автор не указал папки, пусть заменит на свою дерикторию

Comment: Совершенно верно, это не "чат доска". Поэтому не надо ее засорять своими неграмотными потугами.

Comment: есть кнопка исправить

Comment: Кнопка исправить нужна для тех, кто в принципе понимает, о чем речь, но допустил опечатку. А не чтобы вытирать сопли тем, кто пишет код от балды, ваще не понимая что он делает.

Comment: dirname(__FILE__) дает путь файла, откуда вызван код, для indexa это работает, для вложенных папок нет, автор сам решит, какой путь ему нужен, а так у него наглядный полный путь, если он выведет  на печать

Comment: Профессиональная пригодность программиста определяется не умением заучивать наизусть значения функций - это может и попугай. А умение читать код и анализировать его на предмет того, подходят ли отдельные  его части друг другу.

Comment: а если у автора форум с несколькими .htaccess файлами? и он не хочет удалять htaccess в принцепе, то именно так и нужно писать путь.

Comment: OMG. Вот так разговариваешь с человеком, и думаешь что у него есть мозги. А потом он пишет вот это

Comment: за что stackoverflow не любят,так это за умников, которые по делу ничего не говорят.. можете дальше троллинг разводить. я молчу.